# Computing a binomial series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I compute the following series:

```
Module[{n = 10^6},
       Sqrt[n] * (4^-n) * NSum[Binomial[2*n - 1, n - k]/((2 k - 1)^2 + Pi^2), {k, 1, n}]]
```

including the cases where n=10^7 and n=10^8?

While trying to compute the first variant, I get the following message from *Mathematica 9*:

> "SequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be
>   determined, and the result may be incorrect."

Comment: Your code with n=10^6 results in 0.07008325392226862. n=10^7 in 0.07012898456782017. No messages.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your original question regarding the proper use of `NSum`, but I'd like to point out that Mathematica can return a symbolic result in this case for arbitrary $n$:

```
Sqrt[n]/4^n Sum[Binomial[2*n - 1, n - k]/((2 k - 1)^2 + Pi^2), {k, 1, n}]
```

which produces

$$\frac{2^{-2 n-1} \sqrt{n} \binom{2 n-1}{n-1} \left((\pi -i) \, _3F_2\left(1,1-n,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \pi
   }{2};n+1,\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i \pi }{2};-1\right)+(\pi +i) \, _3F_2\left(1,1-n,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \pi
   }{2};n+1,\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i \pi }{2};-1\right)\right)}{\pi +\pi ^3}.$$

Unfortunately, evaluation of `HypergeometricPFQ` is very slow at large values of `n`, so this is not too helpful.

Answer (score 3):

What's the exact version of your *Mathematica*? On v9.0.1, Win 64bit, I can't reproduce the warning with `n=10^6` or `n=10^7` or `n=10^8`. According to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834/1871), `SequenceLimit::seqlim` is a evidence that `NSum` has chosen method `"WynnEpsilon"`, but according to the timing and memory usage, `NSum` probably choose `"EulerMaclaurin"` when solving your specific problem. Anyway, I managed to get the warning by raising `n` to `10^10` and explicitly setting `Method` to `"WynnEpsilon"`:

```
$Version
Module[{n = 10^10}, 
  Sqrt[n]*(4^-n)*
   NSum[Binomial[2*n - 1, n - k]/((2 k - 1)^2 + Pi^2), {k, 1, n}, 
    Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

And the warning will disappear if I set a higher `WorkingPrecision`:

```
Module[{n = 10^10}, 
  Sqrt[n]*(4^-n)*
   NSum[Binomial[2*n - 1, n - k]/((2 k - 1)^2 + Pi^2), {k, 1, n}, 
    Method -> "WynnEpsilon", WorkingPrecision -> 30]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]